# Undo a git merge when it has been pushed

Tags: git, version-control, git-push

How can I undo a merge when I have already pushed to master after merge? 
Here are my steps:

1. `git add -A`
2. `git commit -m "some message"`
3. `git fetch origin master:master`
4. `git rebase master (resolve merge conflicts)`
5. `git push -f origin my local branch`

I want to go back to the state where i was at step 2

Comment: You can do `git checkout <commit no>`, and go back to the previous state. Get the commit id from `git log`, and then once you do checkout, code will be in detached state. So to comeout of that, do `git checkout -b old_branch`. and then push `git push -f origin mylocalbranch`.

Comment: That won't always work. @Sahil

Comment: I actually used rebase not merge. I edited the question.

Comment: in your answer what is the difference between old_branch and mylocalbranch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **force pushed**, meaning you *overwrote* the changes on a remote.  **Your computer** can't fix it; however, if there is another computer with a local copy before you force pushed, you can force push from that computer and overwrite your force push.

> Git's push --force is destructive because it unconditionally
>   overwrites the remote repository with whatever you have locally,
>   possibly overwriting any changes that a team member has pushed in the
>   meantime. **- [Atlaissan Git Resource](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/04/force-with-lease/)**

There are some cases where checking out to an old commit and then force pushing that might work, but I suspect that probably won't work in your case because you had to force push your changes.