# Git - Force remote branch to match local

Tags: git

So an error happened at my `Openshift` respository, and now I need to upload the project again, however when I do

```
git commit -am "some text"
git push
```

I get the message "Everything is up to date", I now want know how exactly I can force my local version to the remote one at which `Openshift` uses.

I can see that people are talking about making a "bare" version of the project, but I don't know what they are talking about, and I'm not that familiar with git for me to dare test a whole lot of things, so a nice "ready to use" solution would be gold ;-)

**EDIT**

As suggested by the comment I tried the ´git push -f origin master` but I get the same result.

Here's a screenshot of my command prompt:[image]

Comment: `git push -f <the_remote_repo> <some references>` forcibly changes mentioned references in the `remote_repo`

Comment: I suppose that `git push -f origin master` will do the trick in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the situation is pretty clear. You haven't created any new commit yet, so there's nothing to push. Look at that `Nothing to commit, working directory clean`.

If you really need to create a commit without any change, you may use `git commit --allow-empty -m "empty commit"`. However I'd suggest to create a new file or change an existing one, and commit the changes. After that you may check if the commit was actually created, using `git log`. Then you may retry the push w/ `git push origin master`, I'm sure you'll succeed this time.

Answer (score 14):

You are looking for `git push -f origin branch-name`.

See my other stack overflow answer on how git force pushing works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35532104/4490559).